# Rig deforms my mesh

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I rigged this robot here and weight painted its arm. The joints are right I think because the other arm moves fine, but when i rotate this one the mesh becomes deformed. I don't know what the problem is, I've made sure to paint the entire arm too.

[image]

Comment: If a part of your robot does not deform, can simply parent the part directly to the bone, without having an armature modifier.  Can you upload your blend https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: it looks like a dirty weight painting. Try to use another approach - just go to the edit mode, select the whole arm, and set its vertex group's weight with the assign button (weight = 1). I think it will do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a vertex to solidly move with a bone, assigning a weight of 1.0 is not enough: you need also to delete any weight referred to every other bone: It looks like the deforming vertices of your mesh are weighted also to some others bones.
To check one vertex and see which weights it has, select it in edit mode and search in the "N" properties panel the "vertex weight" panel.
[image]